# Get Android system accent color (Android 10 System color accent)

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-10.0

This question should be simple, but i didn't find an answer. I have an app with selectable accent, and i'm trying to add an option to use the android system accent (apps like Lawnchair have such an option). In the style for the system accent, i tried to get this accent in every way possible:

`?android:colorAccent`

`?android:attr/colorAccent`

`?attr/colorAccent`

And this is the style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.systemAccent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">???</item>
</style>
```

Nothing seems to work and the app crashes, but i'm certain that this is possible. The accent selection, when i use normal colors, works fine. Where am i wrong?

EDIT: Just to be clear, i'm trying to get the system accent color, i.e. the system wide color used in settings, notification panel and so on. This color is now selectable in Android 10 and was selectable before in rom like the Oxygen OS. Let's say i select a red accent in settings->customization on my **Android 10 device**. I want to get this red accent in my app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it programmatically:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
     android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);
contextThemeWrapper.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorAccent,
     typedValue, true);
int color = typedValue.data;
```

Just to be clear I am referring to the Android Q System color accent:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not sure this answers my question. I'm trying to get the system accent color, i.e. the system wide color used in settings, notification panel and so on. This color is now selectable in Android 10 and was selectable before in rom like the Oxygen OS. Let's say i select a red accent in settings->customization on my Android 10 device. I want to get this red accent in my app.

Comment: @m.i.n.a.r. My bad. I've updated the answer. Really I don't know if you can refer it inside a style.

Comment: Thanks! Probably the app I was referring to (Lawnchair) gets this color programmatically. In this case, I'll have to rethink the way the accent is selected, sadly.

Comment: When i execute your snippet of code i get something like `-8336444`. Maybe i'm wrong, but it doesn't seem a color. D: But either way, since themes are immutable  i can't find a way to use this color. I'll give up on this for now.

Comment: @m.i.n.a.r. I tryed to use the color in some views and it works.

Comment: Yep, you're right. But i tried using this color to set the statusbar color and it's not the right one. My accent is blue (i also tried changing it), and i get the classical teal accent from android 5 and above. Probably something related to how accents are managed on my device (Oneplus 7 pro, Oxygen 10.0.1). Anroid isn't ready for a real system wide theming imho. Just the automatic dark-light stuff works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I did some intensive research and trial and error. After that I found out, that I could access a private property `@*android:color/accent_device_default_light`. **BUT** this is just possible if you change your parent class for the activity from `AppCompatActivity` to `Activity` because the AppCompat can't set up the toolbar with this private property. Further it's not recommended to use private properties because they are likely to get deleted or changed in the future.

Comment: Seems like Android itself doesn't encourage this. And i thought it was simple :D Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetEdit (or similar application) to enumerate it.  Look for the `sysui_type_accent_color` key under the Secure table.  You can also do this programatically, if I recall correctly, through `adb shell` via `busybox content`.

Answer (score -1):

@color/colorAccent
use this ,it's default color in android
or you can customize your color in the color.xml

Comment: I edited the question, probably I wasn't clear enough :)